# How to populate a submit popup based on the value you filled to evaluate a condition | flask

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a jinja html template which has a form. The form is a wtforms , assume it like

```
>>> from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, IntegerField, SelectField, StringField, validators
>>> class COOLForm(Form):
       action = SelectField('Action', description='Action', choices=[('online', 'ONLINE'), ('offline', 'OFFLINE')])
...
```

The html template looks something like

```
<div class = "major"
<form id="blah">
<input type="hidden">
      {{ forms.form_field(coolform.action) }}
.
.
</div>
```

Then in the same file i have a `submit` div where i want to evalute the condition if a user seleted ONLINE or OFFLINE, i will show a different content.

something like

```
{% if coolform.action. == "online" or coolform.action. == "ONLINE" %}
blah
{%else%}
blah
```

I am not able to check how can I do that if condition

Comment: Please refer my answer to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58870595/6695608

Comment: okay cool  checking