# How to evaluate this condition in HTML jinja template based on id

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Assume i have

```
      <tr>
        <th>Action</th>
        <td id="action_id"></td>
      </tr>
```

Now i want to write a condition where i display something based on the value of action_id, i.e

```
{% if action_id == "on" %}
     display
{%else%}
```

I am trying to display this , this is related to [How to populate a submit popup based on the value you filled to evaluate a condition | flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851035/how-to-populate-a-submit-popup-based-on-the-value-you-filled-to-evaluate-a-condi)

Comment: So what is your question exactly ?

Comment: how can i evaluation the condtion i mentioned. since this is a flask jinja html template. equivalent of $('#action').val();

Comment: It is exactly the way you have already mentioned in your post, you simply pass the variable to the template and then just check it `{% if action_id == "on" %} {{ action_id }} {% endif %}`.

Comment: its not working . i tried with `{% if action_id == "on" %}` i am always ending up in the `%else%` part

Comment: action_id is a javascript object

Comment: @Rohit More here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851035/how-to-populate-a-submit-popup-based-on-the-value-you-filled-to-evaluate-a-condi

Comment: are you sure the value of `action_id` is indeed string `on`, does the `if` condition evaluate to `true` inside your `view` ?

Comment: yes it is .. but the thing is its a javascript object which i am trying to access

Comment: Well in that case you should be doing with javascript code and not in the actual template code. Jinja2 template engine only has access to the variables which are actually passed to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 Template Engine has access to only those variables which are passed to it via the view function, and since the variable which you are trying to evaluate is an HTML element you need to access this variable and do your checking using javascript.

Template Engine does not know what this variable is since it is neither passed via your view function nor it is declared inside the template, hence your `if` condition always fails.

You can achieve this using standard javascript by putting it at the end of your template using the `script` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let id_element = $(#action_id).val()
if (id_element === 'on'){
// do your stuff here
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have a bunch of table rows inside the if block

Comment: That you need to handle using javascript, you can still access template variables inside the `script` tag.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer has accepted if it solves your original issue and try asking a newer question for a newer issue.

Comment: i am not sure how to use Javascript at all.

Comment: Well take it as a learning opportunity then, if you have specific question about how to do something with javascript try asking a new question and mark this as solved so that others know your original issue is resolved.